# d3.js drag node boundaries not working for linked path

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to keep the draggable nodes within the set boundaries, which i have managed to do.
I am not sure why when i reach the boundary the node stops and the path carries on to wherever the mouse is.

Here's an example of whats happening [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mattstudios/qp0ts5bz/)

```
    var width = 400,
      height = 400;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
      .size([width, height])
      .on("tick", tick);

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)
      .on("click", explicitlyPosition);

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
      node = svg.selectAll(".node");

    function tick() {
      text.attr("transform", transform);
      link.attr("d", linkArc);

      var radius = 15;
      var dx = function(d) {
        return Math.max(radius, Math.min(width - radius, d.x))
      }
      var dy = function(d) {
        return Math.max(radius, Math.min(height - radius, d.y))
      }

      node.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + dx(d) + "," + dy(d) + ")";
      });

      link.attr("x1", function(d) {
          return d.source.x;
        })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
          return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
          return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
          return d.target.y;
        });




    }

    function explicitlyPosition() {
      node.each(function(d) {
        d.x = 0;
        d.y = 0;
        d.fixed = false;
      });
      tick();
      node.each(function(d) {
        d.fixed = true;
      });
      force.resume();
    }

    var graph = {
      "nodes": [{
        "id": "aa",
        "x": 100,
        "y": 250,
        "fixed": true
      }, {
        "id": "bb",
        "x": 200,
        "y": 200,
        "fixed": true
      }, {
        "id": "cc",
        "x": 200,
        "y": 300,
        "fixed": true
      }, {
        "id": "dd",
        "x": 300,
        "y": 250,
        "fixed": true
      }, {
        "id": "ee",
        "x": 350,
        "y": 300,
        "fixed": true
      }, {
        "id": "ff",
        "x": 250,
        "y": 250,
        "fixed": true
      }],
      "links": [{
        "source": "aa",
        "target": "bb",
        "type": "type1"
      }, {
        "source": "bb",
        "target": "cc",
        "type": "type1"
      }, {
        "source": "cc",
        "target": "dd",
        "type": "type3"
      }, {
        "source": "bb",
        "target": "dd",
        "type": "type1"
      }, {
        "source": "bb",
        "target": "dd",
        "type": "type2"
      }]
    };

    var edges = [];
    graph.links.forEach(function(e) {
      var sourceNode = graph.nodes.filter(function(n) {
          return n.id === e.source;
        })[0],
        targetNode = graph.nodes.filter(function(n) {
          return n.id === e.target;
        })[0];

      edges.push({
        source: sourceNode,
        target: targetNode,
        type: e.type
      });
    });
    console.log(edges);
    //any links with duplicate source and target get an incremented 'linknum'
    for (var i = 0; i < edges.length; i++) {
      if (i != 0 &&
        edges[i].source == edges[i - 1].source &&
        edges[i].target == edges[i - 1].target) {
        edges[i].linknum = edges[i - 1].linknum + 1;
      } else {
        edges[i].linknum = 1;
      };
    };

    force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(edges)
      .start();

    link = link.data(edges)
      .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        return "link " + d.type;
      })
      .attr("marker-end", function(d) {
        return "url(#" + d.type + ")";
      })
      .attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
      })
      .attr("y1", function(d) {
        return d.source.y;
      })
      .attr("x2", function(d) {
        return d.target.x;
      })
      .attr("y2", function(d) {
        return d.target.y;
      })
      .attr("d", linkArc);

    var node_drag = self.force = d3.behavior.drag()
      .on("dragstart", dragstart)
      .on("drag", dragmove)
      .on("dragend", dragend);

    node = node.data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 8)
      .call(node_drag);


    function linkArc(d) {
      var curve = 2;
      var homogeneous = 3.2;
      var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) * (d.linknum + homogeneous) / (curve * homogeneous); //linknum is defined above
      return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    }

    function transform(d) {

      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    }

    function dragstart(d, i) {
      force.stop(); // stops the force auto positioning before you start dragging
    }

    function dragmove(d, i) {
      d.px += d3.event.dx;
      d.py += d3.event.dy;
      d.x += d3.event.dx;
      d.y += d3.event.dy;
      tick();
    }

    function dragend(d, i) {
      d.fixed = true; // of course set the node to fixed so the force doesn't include the node in its auto positioning stuff
      tick();
      force.resume();
    }

    var text = svg.append("g").selectAll("text")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("text")
      .attr("x", 8)
      .attr("y", ".31em")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.id;
      });

    // Per-type markers, as they don't inherit styles.
    svg.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
      .data(["type1", "type2", "type3"])
      .enter().append("svg:marker")
      .attr("id", String)
      .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
      .attr("refX", 15)
      .attr("refY", -1.5)
      .attr("markerWidth", 6)
      .attr("markerHeight", 6)
      .attr("orient", "auto")
      .append("svg:path")
      .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
```

I am new to using d3.js and i don't really know what to look for to fix this, any help would be great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the boundaries inside `dragmove`, instead of inside `tick`:

```
function dragmove(d, i) {
    d.x = d.x > width ? width : d.x < 0 ? 0 : d.x + d3.event.dx;
    d.y = d.y > height ? height : d.y < 0 ? 0 : d.y + d3.event.dy;
    tick();
}
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0v21Lhk3/

Comment: I have just noticed the d.y line "width" should be changed "height".

Comment: Thanks for noticing that.